# xcodebuild: ios app with watchapp, provide Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

I need to be able to build my iOS app from command line, specifying appropriate certificates and provisioning profiles. It is not much of a problem if the app consists of just 1 target, but in my case it has a watchkit extension and a watch app as well, and those have their own provisioning profiles.

Is there a way to specify which profiles to use for each of those targets? Or do i have to build the whole thing somehow by component and then assemble it into a single apk?

Comment: You should be able to specify these in the Xcode Project settings. AFAIK there's no command line flag/option equivalent for specifying multiple values.

Comment: Just for clarification: if you set the correct settings in Xcode Project Settings you can simply call `xcodebuild -project/-workspace PROJECT_FILE -scheme THE_SCHEME archive` and it should use the values specified in the Xcode Project Settings.

Comment: I want to be able to configure each build without having to change the project settings, as I don't want to impose the CI settings on the rest of the developers.

Comment: You can add new Configurations/Schemes to your project, specifically for these cases. There might be a different solution, but AFAIK there's no multi option solution accessible as just an `xcodebuild` param.